# acpi_idle vs. intel_idle

Tags: cpu, sles

There are two SLES 11 servers:

```
SERVER311:~ # cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver
acpi_idle
SERVER311:~ #
```

and:

```
SERVER705:~ # cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver
intel_idle
SERVER705:~ #
```

Both having the:

```
intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=0
```

in the: "/boot/grub/menu.lst", were rebooted.

**The question:** what is the difference between acpi_idle and intel_idle ?

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/454896/120445) and [its answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454980/120445) contain a deep dive into the `intel_idle` driver and also compare its behavior to the `acpi_driver`.

Comment: I just want to point out that the question was asked by Peter and commented upon by Parker. What are the odds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Both are different implementations of CPU idle drivers. acpi_idle is the default driver, supports all CPU architectures, while intel_idle is Intel CPUs specific.

**More details**:
The API for a CPU idle driver is defined in include/linux/cpuidle.h. It defines the "generic framework for CPU idle power management". acpi_idle driver (defined in drivers/acpi/processor_idle.c) implements this behaviour for all CPU architectures. intel_idle (defined in drivers/idle/intel_idle.c) is an idle driver designed specifically for modern Intel CPUs (from the comments in the intel_idle.c header):

> /*  * intel_idle.c - native hardware idle loop for modern Intel
>   processors  * ...
>
> /*  * intel_idle is a cpuidle driver that loads on specific Intel
>   processors  * in lieu of the legacy ACPI processor_idle driver.  The
>   intent is to  * make Linux more efficient on these processors, as
>   intel_idle knows  * more than ACPI, as well as make Linux more immune
>   to ACPI BIOS bugs.  */

So for modern Intel CPUs you should use the intel_idle driver since it is designed specifically for increasing Intel CPUs' efficiency.

So why would some setups load with intel_idle and some with acpi_idle? This is what stated in the commit message introducing the intel_idle driver:

> commit 2671717265ae6e720a9ba5f13fbec3a718983b65
>
> Author: Len Brown Date:   Mon Mar 8 14:07:30 2010 -0500
>
> intel_idle: native hardware cpuidle driver for latest Intel processors
>
> This EXPERIMENTAL driver supersedes acpi_idle on Intel Atom
>   Processors, Intel Core i3/i5/i7 Processors and associated Intel Xeon
>   processors.
>
> It does not support the Intel Core2 processor or earlier.
>
> For kernels configured with ACPI, CONFIG_INTEL_IDLE=y allows
>   intel_idle to probe before the ACPI processor driver. Booting with
>   "intel_idle.max_cstate=0" disables intel_idle and the system will fall
>   back on ACPI's "acpi_idle".
>
> Typical Linux distributions load ACPI processor module early, making
>   CONFIG_INTEL_IDLE=m not easily useful on ACPI platforms.
>
> intel_idle probes all processors at module_init time. Processors that
>   are hot-added later will be limited to using C1 in idle.
>
> Signed-off-by: Len Brown

So the reasons are:

1. Non-Intel CPU on the system or older Intel architectures.
2. Not marked CONFIG_INTEL_IDLE=y in .config
3. Booting with intel_idle.max_cstate=0 in cmdline

Since you said you set #3 on both setups the question is why one of them loaded with intel_idle. Try 'cat /proc/cmdline' and make sure the option is really set. Also, check the differences between the architectures with 'lscpu' or 'cat /proc/cpuinfo'

Answer (score 0):

The other answer summarized differences really well, intel_idle vs acpi_idle.

Giving additional info on how to enable each of the drivers. This assumes kernel was built with CONFIG_INTEL_IDLE=y.

- **intel_idle**: Enable C-States on platform BIOS, and do not use any kernel boot argument, then check that `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver` shows `intel_idle`.
- **acpi_idle**: Enable C-States on platform BIOS, use intel_idle.max_cstate=0 kernel boot argument, check current_driver is `acpi_idle`.
- **Fully disable C-States**: Disable C-States on platform BIOS, include intel_idle.max_cstate=0 kernel boot argument, check current_driver is `none`.